# apply different functions to different columns of a data frame and repeat the same for multiple data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to write a piece of code that performs a set of actions on different columns of a data frame (one action per column) and can be repeated on multiple data frames that follow the same column layout.

So far I have been doing this by creating one resultant data frame for each input data frame and redoing this for all the data frames I have.

```
result_df_1 = data.frame (c1 = sum(ip_df$c1[which(ip_df$c1 == 1)],
                         .
                         .
                        )

result_df_2 = data.frame (c1 = sum(ip_df$c1[which(ip_df$c1 == 1)],
                         .
                         .
                        )

.
.
result_df_21 = data.frame (c1 = sum(ip_df$c1[which(ip_df$c1 == 1)],
                         .
                         .
                        )
```

I want to try and automate this process by covering the following for the input data frame. As a snapshot, I want to carry out the following,

```
col_1 = sum-if(col_val=1),
col_2 = sum-if(col-val>0)
col_3 = mean-if(col_val>0)
col_4 = sum-if(col_val = 1)
col_5 = sum-if(col_val = 1)
col_6 = sum-if(col_val = 1)
col_7 = sum-if(col_val = 1)

.
.
.
```

The sample of the data is as given below

```
c1|c2|c3|c4|c5|c6|c7
1 | 4| 8| 1| 1| 0|0
1 | 0| 6| 1| 1| 0|0
0 | 3| 9| 0| 1| 1|0

Store the results of the operations (above) in col_8 to col_11 in a temp_df (below). 

temp_df_1 = data.frame(col_8 = (col_4*col_3)
                     col_9 = (col_4*col_3)
                     col_10 = (col_4*col_3)
                     col_11 = (col_4*col_3)
                     )
```

Each data frame has about 32 columns and I have 21 data frames that I need to replicate these simple actions on. 
The resultant goes into a data frame with one column, for each data frame, that is the sum of the 4 columns that are stored in temp_df (col_8 to col_11) above.

```
res_df = data.frame(res_df1 = c(rowSums(temp_df1),
                    res_df2 = c(rowSums(temp_df2),
                    .
                    .
                    res_df21 = c(rowSums(temp_df21)
                   )
```

So far I have been doing this manually and want to automate this given that I need to do this for a lot more data and my method is very very inefficient currently. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some sample data, current and expected output. This will likely make the post more intuitive.

Comment: @NelsonGon I have added a sample of the data. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best would be to prepare a function detecting the column to know which function to call. I won't do it in your place (cause it would be harsh work and you wouldn't learn anything) but here are the best tips I could offer:

- `lapply()` is your friend to navigate through columns
- `do.call()` is what you need to call function(s). Also learn about `symbol` type and `eval()` function.
- `switch()` can be clean to detect the column content, but a sequence of`if`will do the work as well. Try also `ifelse()`

I hope this will help you. In last resort, I had similar issue and will redirect you to a git of mine, but I prefer to see people learn ;)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will look at the what you have suggested and hopefully come back with some working code soon :). Also just to clarify, was not posting this to get a canned solution (but can't lie, getting one would have been just as great!!!!) :D

Comment: About clear solution, I do post them when I feel people are training to R, or if it is about miscellaneous functionalities. But in your case, I know by experience this will help you to learn to work with those functions.